# UISplitViewCOntroller + TabBarCOntroller + iPad

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I am developing a tab-based iPad application in which corresponding to each tab, I have to show an UISplitViewController . I have done this by adding two navigation controllers to my tabBarController and assigning a subclass of UISplitViewController as RootViewController of both  navigationController. And also I have to show both viewControllers(Master and Detail) in both modes(Potrait and Landscape). For this I have constructed a subclass of UISplitViewController in which i am overriding

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation
```

method and setting the frame of both ViewControllers as demonstrated in  [this](http://blog.blackwhale.at/tag/uisplitviewcontroller/) link. However i am not able to set both viewControllers correctly.If my app starts in Landscape mode everything displays fine but if i open it in Potrait mode then the orientation of both ViewControllers changes. Sometimes the MasterView occupies the entire screen or sometimes both ViewControllers appear leaving a black line between them and the navigationBar. I have been banging my head over this problem since two days without any success.

kindly help..

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to add a `UISplitViewController` to a `UITabBarController` and allow all the components to play together nicely?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this same example and I ran into this and other weirdness but I did get it showing properly in various orientations.  The trick was to do the same frame detection stuff in the individual views as well on their viewdidload method and resize appropriately.